# Why is Live Preview scrolling to the top of page after every change?

Tags: craft3, live-preview

Having an issue with Live Preview scrolling to the top of the page in the preview area on every update made (even title field). Narrowed it down to it *not* being a browser issue as it works plum good on another site. Here’s the error I’m seeing in console with the site giving me the issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please and thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3FNt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The issue was related to Font Awesome 5's SVG replacement with JS method but specifically [Asynchronous Loading Indicators](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/performance-and-security#async-loading-indicators). Once I stopped using this async stuff all is peachy again.